# SAS include dynamic path

Tags: macros, sas, execute

I have tryed build little macro which in loop it should runother SAS programs.
Table Control_files has two field, where are other part of path to proper sas program.

```
%LET PATH_TO = '%include "T:\XXX\YYY\ZZZ\';
%LET PATH_end = '.sas"';
data _null_;
set CONTROL_FILES;
call execute ('%runlimitsquery('||&PATH_TO||SCHEMA_NAME||'\'||PROCES_NAME||&PATH_end||');');
run;
```

I tryed used runlimitsquery because I found somewhere that tip..
When I run my code, log returns:

```
NOTE: CALL EXECUTE generated line.
NOTE: Line generated by the CALL EXECUTE routine.
1         + %runlimitsquery(%include "T:\XXX\YYY\ZZZ\XXX_TECHNICAL_AAAAA\001_AAAAA.sas");
            _
            180
WARNING: Apparent invocation of macro RUNLIMITSQUERY not resolved.

ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Build your string first in a variable, ensure it's created correctly and then pass it to call execute. That's usually where the error is. Also make sure the macro is compiled first, which seems to be part of the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have answer for my problem...
Below code works:

```
%LET PATH_TO = '%include "T:\XXX\YYY\ZZZ\';
%LET PATH_end = '.sas"';
data _null_;
set CONTROL_FILES;
call execute ('('||&PATH_TO.||SCHEMA_NAME||'\'||PROCES_NAME||&PATH_end.||';');
run;
```

Comment: Is `%runlimitsquery` an automatic sas macro? If not you have to explicitly define it. Otherwise, the straight `%include` should be all you need.

Comment: Yes, when I deleted `%runlimitsquery` and one bracket in the commend it started to work