# SAS Macro in macro - how change the process?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

You wrote that I shouldn't set %macro in %macro. so please help in my process.
Genesis: I have one table where is stock all SAS processes which starting day by day - but various of report should be run various day - according to field "Nr_week_day". If today is contained in this field - I put this process to general_stock table to run.
Below is my code with comment - what I'm trying to get.
Generally - this code works, but it with macro in macro. maybe you have better idea what can work it.
This process is related with my another "questions":
[SAS include dynamic path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53213087/sas-include-dynamic-path)
[SAS Macro in macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53231450/sas-macro-in-macro)

```
    data CONTROL_FILES_BASE;
       input  Priority : 2.
              ACTIVE: 1.
              PROCES_NAME: $10.
              Nr_week_day: $10.

    ;   cards;
    1 1 TEST_01 (1,3,6)
    2 1 TEST_02 0
    3 1 TEST_03 (4,5)
    ;

    Data Kalendariusz;
    infile cards dlm=',' dsd;
       input  ref_date: date9.
              Nr_day_of_month
              Nr_week_day
              Number_date;
        Format ref_date DDMMYY10.;
    cards;
    01NOV2018,  1,  4,  20181101
    02NOV2018,  2,  5,  20181102
    03NOV2018,  3,  6,  20181103
    04NOV2018,  4,  7,  20181104
    05NOV2018,  5,  1,  20181105
    06NOV2018,  6,  2,  20181106
    07NOV2018,  7,  3,  20181107
    08NOV2018,  8,  4,  20181108
    09NOV2018,  9,  5,  20181109
    10NOV2018,  10, 6,  20181110
    11NOV2018,  11, 7,  20181111
    12NOV2018,  12, 1,  20181112
    13NOV2018,  13, 2,  20181113
    14NOV2018,  14, 3,  20181114
    15NOV2018,  15, 4,  20181115
    16NOV2018,  16, 5,  20181116
    17NOV2018,  17, 6,  20181117
    18NOV2018,  18, 7,  20181118
    19NOV2018,  19, 1,  20181119
    20NOV2018,  20, 2,  20181120
    21NOV2018,  21, 3,  20181121
    22NOV2018,  22, 4,  20181122
    23NOV2018,  23, 5,  20181123
    24NOV2018,  24, 6,  20181124
    25NOV2018,  25, 7,  20181125
    26NOV2018,  26, 1,  20181126
    27NOV2018,  27, 2,  20181127
    28NOV2018,  28, 3,  20181128
    29NOV2018,  29, 4,  20181129
    30NOV2018,  30, 5,  20181130
    ;

    /*COMMENT: I TAKE TODAY IN VARIABLE*/
    %LET EXTRACT_DATE_DT = date();

    /*COMMENT: I CREATE EMPTY TABLE TO STOCK OF PROCESS*/
    Proc sql;
    Create table GENERAL_STOCK as
    Select
    *
    FROM WORK.CONTROL_FILES_BASE
    WHERE ACTIVE = 2
    ;quit;

   /*START MAIN MACRO*/ 
    %macro GENERATE_STOCK();

    /*COMMENT: I check how many processes should be generated.*/
        PROC SQL noprint;
            Select
            count(*) into :i
            From work.CONTROL_FILES_BASE
            WHERE Nr_week_day <> '0'
        ;quit;
    %PUT &i;

    /*COMMENT: I separated process which should be check*/
    Proc sql;
    Create table STOCK_2 as
    Select
    monotonic() as ROW_ID,
    *
    FROM work.CONTROL_FILES_BASE
    WHERE Nr_week_day ne '0'
    ;quit;

    /*MAIN LOOP - I take field NR_WEEK_DAY and will check that this number of day is today - row by row*/
    %do ITER = 1 %To &i;

                Proc sql;
                Select
                    Nr_week_day into :SET_VAR
                    from STOCK_2
                    WHERE ROW_ID = &ITER
                ;quit;
            %PUT &SET_VAR;
    /*SET_VAR have value from Nr_week_day*/

        %LET l_decision = 0;/*I set default value in variable*/
    /*below code I found in forum - this macro reverse query - check whether (1,3,6) is included today - in table KALENDARIUSZ*/
            %macro nos_obs(dsn=,where_stmt=);
                proc sql;
                    select 
                    count(*) 
                    into :l_decision
                    from &dsn.
                    &where_stmt.
                ;quit;
            %mend ;
            %nos_obs(dsn=Kalendariusz,where_stmt=where Nr_week_day in &&SET_VAR. and Ref_date = &EXTRACT_DATE_DT.);
        %PUT &l_decision;

    /*IF ABOVE CODE RETURN 1 -  means that the nr_week_day is today */
        /*When l_decisions is 1 then process should add this row to general_stock. If 0 - should add nothing.*/
        %if &l_decision = 1 %then
            %do;
                Proc sql;
                Create table STOCK_2_INSERT (drop=ROW_ID) as
                Select
                *
                FROM WORK.STOCK_2
                WHERE ROW_ID = &ITER
                ;quit;

                Proc sql;
                    insert into GENERAL_STOCK
                    select * from work.STOCK_2_INSERT
                ;quit;

                /*I clear temp table*/
                Proc sql;
                    delete FROM WORK.STOCK_2_INSERT
                ;quit;
            %end;
        %else %if &l_decision = 0 %then
            %do;
            %end;
    %end;
    %mend GENERATE_STOCK;
    %GENERATE_STOCK();

/*AND I LOOK AT GENERAL TABLE*/
    Proc sql;
    Create table SHOW_GENERAL_STOCK as
    Select
    *
    FROM WORK.GENERAL_STOCK
    ;quit;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the answers to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53231450/sas-macro-in-macro), it's a bad idea to define a macro within another macro definition.  In your example, what that means is you can move the definition of the utility macro %nos_obs:

```
%macro nos_obs(dsn=,where_stmt=);
  proc sql;
    select 
    count(*) 
    into :l_decision
    from &dsn.
    &where_stmt.
    ;quit;
%mend ;
```

That block of code should not be inside the block:

```
%macro GENERATE_STOCK;
   ...
%mend GENERATE_STOCK;
```

You can still call %nos_obs from within %generate_stock.  Just don't nest the macro definitions. So you end up with:

```
*define a macro;
%macro nos_obs(dsn=,where_stmt=);
...
%mend ;

*define a macro that does some stuff and invokes another macro;
%macro GENERATE_STOCK;
   ...
   %nos_obs(dsn=...)
   ...
%mend GENERATE_STOCK;

%generatestock
```

That's the general point about not nesting macro definitions.  To your big picture, it looks like you are writing a scheduler in SAS.  Like linux cron or windows scheduler where you decide which programs to run based on the day of the week.  **Usually it is better to use a dedicated scheduler solution (cron, LSF, windows scheduler etc.) rather that write your own.**  Better means easier, more maintainable, more flexible, etc. They will let you manage dependencies, pause and restart, etc etc.

That said, if you do write your own scheduler in SAS (lots of people do, it's hard to resist the temptation sometimes), I think the code you have shown is much more complex than it needs to be.

You have a control dataset that lists the days on which each process should run:

```
data CONTROL_FILES_BASE;
   input  Priority : 2.
          ACTIVE: 1.
          PROCES_NAME: $10.
          Nr_week_day: $10.

;   cards;
1 1 TEST_01 (1,3,6)
2 1 TEST_02 0
3 1 TEST_03 (4,5)
;
```

If you want to determine which processes should run today, you just need to find out what day of the week it is today, and select the records accordingly.  Something like:

```
data General_Stock ;
  set CONTROL_FILES_BASE ;
  where findc(Nr_week_day,put(weekday(today()),1.)) ;
run ;
```

When I'm writing this it's Saturday, so weekday(today()) returns 7 and the above selects 0 records, because there are no processes scheduled to run on Saturdays.

If you want a macro, because you want to test to see which processes your control dataset will trigger on different dates, you can write a little macro where you input the extract date. Something like:

```
%macro GENERATE_STOCK
  (data=/*name of input control dataset*/
  ,out= /*name of output dataset*/
  ,ExtractDate=/*extract date is a SAS date or expression like today() */
  );

  data &out ;
    set &data ;
    where findc(Nr_week_day,put(weekday(&extractDate),1.)) ;
  run ;

  title1 "Printout of &out genenerated when ExtractDate=%superq(ExtractDate)" ;
    proc print data=&out ;
    run ;
  title1 ;

%mend GENERATE_STOCK ;
```

Test like:

```
%generate_stock(data=control_files_base,out=wantToday    ,extractdate=today())
%generate_stock(data=control_files_base,out=wantSunday   ,extractdate="11Nov2018"d)
%generate_stock(data=control_files_base,out=wantMonday   ,extractdate="12Nov2018"d)
%generate_stock(data=control_files_base,out=wantTuesday  ,extractdate="13Nov2018"d)
%generate_stock(data=control_files_base,out=wantWednesday,extractdate="14Nov2018"d)
%generate_stock(data=control_files_base,out=wantThursday ,extractdate="15Nov2018"d)
%generate_stock(data=control_files_base,out=wantFriday   ,extractdate="16Nov2018"d)
%generate_stock(data=control_files_base,out=wantSaturday ,extractdate="17Nov2018"d)
```

Comment: Oh my god, this is so easy... Yes, I know that my code is too complicated, but on the one hand I train macros, on the other hand I use only SAS Enterprise Guide where I set my codes below another process - set in timetable by IT. I can run my reports independently from somebody from IT in "time window" (three time by day) - so, that's why I'm writing my own schedule.
Additional question: when I will try check by number day of month I can use these code?:

Comment: I change "findc" for "find" and tested for first day of month (in variable I set day - datka). Works good but can you look at whether it is a good solution?

`data CONTROL_FILES_BASE;
   input  Priority : 2.
          ACTIVE: 1.
          PROCES_NAME: $20.
          Nr_day_month: $20.
;   cards;
1 1 TEST_01 (3,11,12)
2 1 TEST_02 0
3 1 TEST_03 (4,5)
;

%let datka = '01Nov2018'd;
data General_Stock ;
  set CONTROL_FILES_BASE ;
  where find(Nr_day_month,put(day(&datka.),2.)) ;
run ;`

Comment: Yes similar approach should work for dates. I would suggest FINDW instead of FIND.  `find('(3,11,12)','2')`will return 8, because it finds the string '2'. `findw('(3,11,12)','2')` will return 0, because it does not find the word '2'.

Comment: Thank you very much! 
Your help and explanations (for both solutions) are invaluable!